# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser WPF first time slow startup

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

The users of my application should be able to (at runtime) add new control(s) containing a `wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser`

But the first time its added it seems to take between 10-20 seconds for the WebBrowser to actually appear which is unacceptably slow. 
**However, once the first control has loaded, adding more only takes 1-2 seconds.** But I dont want the initial one to take this long.

I am basically just doing the simplest thing possible right now:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.ComponentControls.MyWebBrowserControl"
             xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"

    <Grid>
        <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0"" Address="http://www.google.com" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

- CefSharp version: 63.0.3
- OS: Win 10
- .NET version: 4.6.1
- Platform: x86

**Edit: Downgrading the CefSharp version to 63.0.0 seems to have solved my issue of very slow initial loading.**

Comment: Manually disabling proxy resolution if your not using a proxy usually speech things up a bit https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/63/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L65 What your seeing is abnormally slow. How does it behave if you run on a different machine? Make sure you are running a Release build.

Comment: Well, changing to Release just gives me `[0416/172243.186:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(366)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale ` 
`[0416/172243.199:ERROR:content_client.cc(272)] No data resource available for id 101` and the application does not start. Switching back to Debug, and the webbrowser no longer works. No matter what I do. This is extremely frustrating.

Comment: Sounds like your missing the locales folder. You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample to test in isolation